# timer automatically starts while application launch

Tags: iphone

hi i ma new to iphone. what i did is crating a timer and calling a function afer 4 sec intervel. (I write code for timer in viewdidload).Timer will run automatically while application lunch in simulator it self. But i need the timer will start after first 8 sec and timer will repeat for every 4 sec  how can i done this pls help me post some code. thank in advance.

Comment: Change 4 seconds to 8 seconds for your timer?!

Comment: no after first 8 sec i have to repeat timer for every 4 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a variable

```
BOOL isNotFirstTime;
```

And in the function that gets triggered after each 4 secs add the following code at the starting

```
-(void)AfterFourSecondsFuction
{
 if(!isNotFirstTime)
 {
  isNotFirstTime=YES;
  return;
 }
//YOUR CODE HERE...
}
```

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 timers.  The target of the first 8 second timer can start the second 4 second timer.